# Как передать параметр между методами ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Как получить из формы Post переменную, чтобы потом её вызвать в другом методе контроллера?
Цель такая: Есть база данных. Я ввожу через форму Data. А дальше выводиться список элементов из БД, у которых эта Data совпадает, как это сделать?

Получаю:

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Search(int Price)  
{  
    IEnumerable<Book> books = db.Books;
    ViewBag.Books = books;
    ViewBag.Price = Price;
    return View();    
}
```

Как мне теперь вызвать метод Show(), учитывая эту переменную Price?

Comment: а вы форму в другой метод не можете сразу отправить? зачем костыли какие то нужны?

Comment: также вы можете использовать одно и тоже представление для обычно списка элементов и результатов поиска.

Answer (score 1):

Другой метод можно вызвать следующим образом:

```
return RedirectToAction("Search", new { Price = Data });
```

Где Data - переменная, считанная из формы.

Comment: это не передача параметра, а перенаправление запроса. То есть сервер отдает 301-й заголовок а браузер запрашивает контент по новому адресу. То есть это уже будет совершенно новый запрос со своим контекстом.

Answer (score 0):

Внесите логику из метода show в закрытый метод всего контроллера и вызывайте этот закрытый метод в обоих http методах. Вызывать открытые методы друг из друга в mvc - не лучшая идея.